# How to submit a form in a different page and then make an edit form display after being submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models `User`, `Anime` and `Animelist`.

A `user` is able to add an `anime` to their `animelist`. This works just fine but i don't want a `user` to be able to add the same `anime` countless times to their list.

How can i set it up so after a user adds a anime to their list an edit pop-up form/button pops out with the info they put in.

I have a pop-up window in the animes/show page to reveal a form that a user has to fill to add a anime to their list. Hopefully I'm making my self clear.

Animelist _form

```
 <%= simple_form_for [@anime, @animelist] do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :status %>
   <%= f.input :rating %>
   <%= f.input :rewatched %>
 <% end %>
```

animes/show page pop-up code

```
 <p><a data-open="exampleModal1">Add to Animelist</a></p>
 <div class="reveal form" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
   <%= render partial: 'animelists/form' %>
   <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
 </div>
```

Animelist controller

```
 def new
   @anime = Anime.friendly.find(params[:anime_id])
   @animelist = Animelist.new
 end
 def create
   @anime = Anime.friendly.find(params[:anime_id])
   @animelist = Animelist.new(animelist_params)
   @animelist.user_id = current_user.id
   @animelist.anime_id = @anime.id
   if @animelist.save
     redirect_to :back
   else
     render :new
   end
 end
```

Anime controller

```
 def show
   @anime = Anime.friendly.find(params[:id])
   @animelist = Animelist.new
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you'd do this is to use a [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) on the `AnimeList` model to make sure each `anime_id` is unique when scoped with `user_id`:

```
#app/models/anime_list.rb
class AnimeList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :anime

  validates :anime, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id, message: "%{attribute} already added" } 
end
```

This will make each new `AnimeList` fail if it you're using the same `@anime.id` & `@user.id`, an error which you can output on your form.

---

**Structure**

There are some issues with your overall structure, which should be addressed if you want to show the errors properly:

```
#config/initializers/friendly_id.rb
...
config.use :finders #-> uncomment so you don't need to call Model.friendly.find any more

#config/routes.rb
resources :animes do 
  resources :anime_lists, only: [:create, :destroy], path_names: { create: "add", destroy: "remove" } #-> url.com/animes/:anime_id/add
end

#app/controllers/animes_controller.rb
class AnimesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @anime_list = current_user.anime_lists.new
  end
end

#app/controllers/anime_lists_controller.rb
class AnimeListsController < ApplicationController

   def create
     @anime     = Anime.find params[:anime_id]
     @animelist = current_user.anime_lists.new animelist_params
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js
     end
   end

   def destroy
     @anime     = Anime.find params[:anime_id]
     @animelist = current_user.anime_lists.find(params[:id]).destroy
   end

   private

   def animelist_params
     params.require(:anime_list).permit(:status, :rating, :rewatched).merge(anime_id: @anime.id)
   end
 end
```

This will clean up your controller, to which you'll be able to use:

```
#app/views/anime_lists/create.js.erb
$("#anime_list").html("<%=j render partial: \"anime_list/form\", locals: { anime_list: @anime_list } %>");

#app/views/anime_lists/_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for anime_list, url: anime_anime_list_path(@anime), remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :status %>
   <%= f.input :rating %>
   <%= f.input :rewatched %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

Your error mentions there is no `animelist` method for `User`:

[image]

This means every time your request hits the controller, it's trying to fire `@user.animelist`; since the `animelist` method does not exist, it's spitting out the error.

Always remember that JS/Ajax requests are just `pseudo` requests. Every time you use `HTTP`, you *have* to send a request to the server. That request is then *processed*. You're never in the dark about errors -- they'll always be in the server logs *somewhere*.

I would surmise the issue is to do with the [`CamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (or lack thereof) of your `anime_list` association:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animelists #-> model name "animelist.rb"
  has_many :animes, through: :anime_lists
end

#app/user/animelist.rb
class Animelist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :anime
end
```

On that front, I also made a small error calling `current_user.animelist` -- it should be `current_user.anime_lists` (plural). This will likely fix your issue.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. I'm trying to figure out how to render it in my my animes/show page. I was thinking of doing  `<%= render partial: 'animelists/form', locals: { anime_list: @animelist } %>`  but i get a 500 (Internal Server Error) in the chrome console when i try to submit. Is there another way to render the partial? I feel like I'm doing this wrong

Comment: What does the console say, does it have an error message?

Comment: This is what it shows me  `  http://localhost:3000/animes/kill-la-kill/anime_lists 500 (Internal Server Error)  jquery.self-c64a74367bda6ef8b860f19e74df08927ca99d2be2ac934e9e92d5fd361e0da4.js?body=1:10244   `

Comment: Hmm that generally means there's a problem with the controller code. What about the console, do you see the error - could you take a screenshot for me?

Comment: ![screenshot](http://cl.ly/1T3H2C41213m/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-09%20at%202.55.44%20PM.png) Here is a screen shot

Comment: I forgot to mention that my models name is  `Animelist` not  `AnimeList` so i switched up your code a little bit on my side.

Comment: Thanks for the update - Ill have a look at this in the morning if that's okay? It's almost midnight here :-/

Comment: Yeah, no problem at all. I'll keep trying to figure this out.

Comment: Updated for you buddy!